# Why do we use `this` in CompareTo in Comparable implementations?

Tags: java, collections, constructor, comparator, compareto

I am somewhat new to java and very new to the Collection framework. I know that `this` refers to the current object

```
public class Student implements Comparable <Student> {

    String name;
    int grade;

    public Student(String name, int grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
         return this.name.compareTo(s.name);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + ", " + this.grade;
    }
}
```

Here `this.name` is null and `s.name` does have a value, so what are we trying to do by comparing `this.name.compareTo(s.name);`

Also what really happens when we do `Collections.sort(studentList);` ?

The code snippet is just for demo purposes

Comment: Why do you say `this.name` is empty? Without knowing how the constructor was invoked you cannot know the contents of `this.name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking two different questions, so I will answer them seperately

First one which is *what are we trying to by comparing this.name.compareTo(s.name);*

When the compareTo method is called on an object of class Student, the *this* becomes the calling object. Since the calling object (hopefully) has been initialized properly this.name will be the name of the calling object.

s.name is the name of the Student object passed in to the compareTo method which is again (hopefully) initialized properly and has a name.

What is boils down to is a String variable calling compareTo passing in a String variable to compare with

Second is *what really happens when we do Collections.sort(studentList);*

Here is the JavaDocs on the [Collections.Sort method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) but you are likely asking about what it does relative to your implementation of Comparable. In short it uses your compareTo method when doing the comparisons for the sort

Comment: `Collection.sort(empList)` consider the list is of String type. then what is calling object inside it? I am guessing `empList.get(0).compareTo(empList.get(1))` is this way comparisons takes place?

Comment: The calling object depends on the exact implementation of the sorting algorithm. It will also vary for each iteration of the logic inside the sorting. For example if you have a StudentA in the list it may at some point be both the calling object and parameter (not at the same time)

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems that the `name` is an important property of a `Student` the first thing you should ask yourself is "What is a valid name for a student?" Is `null` valid? Is an empty string valid? If not, you need to prevent the initialization of a `Student` with an invalid `name` by using a setter:

```
public void setName(String name) {
  if (name is invalid) {
    throw error;
  }

  this.name = name; // name is valid, so this is safe now
}
```

Now, call the setter in your constructor and you'll be sure that if you have a `Student`, he'll have a valid `name`.

One problem with having an invalid `name` is that if you don't prevent `null` values you'll get a `NullPointerException` every time you call the `compareTo()` method. You'll essentially be calling `null.compareTo()` and obviously `null` doesn't have such a method, it doesn't have any methods.

Now, to the `sort()` method. How do you sort `Student`s? If you don't tell Java how to compare one `Student` to another `Student`, how should it order them? It can handle numbers (2 is less than 3) and strings ("a" is before "b"), but it can't know how to compare a custom class you created. Therefore, you need to let it know - using the `compareTo()` method. Calling `sort()` on a collection of objects which cannot be compared will cause an exception. Calling `sort()` on a collection of `Student` will order them using the rules you provided in `compareTo()` which is by `name` (regular string comparison).

As for the sorting mechanism itself, it's implementation specific, but it's usually a combination of several algorithms, a hybrid. In Java I believe it's `Timsort`, in C# it's introspective sort. In any case, in order to sort a collection like this, you need to compare elements, two by two (hence the requirement to implement `Comparable`). The trick is how to do this so as to reduce the number of comparisons performed. There are a lot of good sources out there that explain different sorting methods, but it all boils down to being able to compare elements and tell which should come before which.

Comment: The first part of your answer, while good information to consider, does not answer the question he asked.

Comment: The question is unclear, I tried explaining as best I could.

Comment: So this is a question about the use of `this`? Sorry, I reread it several times and still can't figure out whether that's the case. As I understood it, he was unclear as to **why** he needs to implement the `compareTo()` method.

Comment: I removed my last comment because I realized it was rude sorry, I can see how you could miss the importance of `this` since the title doesn't format it specially and it just reads like an awkward sentence if you don't realize it

Comment: Yes, I think the wording is confusing. It's not easy to clearly state a question when English is not your native language. I guess the author can ask for clarifications in a comment if the information provided is not what he was looking for.

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully make it more clear (if the edit gets approved)

Comment: So you want to know how the `sort()` method works, is that it? I edited my answer to include this, I hope this is helpful.